# How to assign string value instead of id in a foreign key column in Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm working on a Django project where I have to assign a string into a foreign key column. But i'm getting error like this **Field 'id' expected a number but got 'string'** for this line
**js.update(Developers=rule[1])**

Here's my model.py

```
class developer(models.Model):  
    Developer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Role = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Level = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Expertise = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Availability_Hours = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Developer_Name
class jira(models.Model):  
    Jira_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, primary_key=True)
    Jira_Story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Short_Description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Story_Points = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Sprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    DX4C_Object = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Developers = models.ForeignKey(developer, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True) 
    Sandbox = models.ForeignKey(environments, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'Mainline': None},blank=True, null=True)
    Epic = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
class assignmentRule(models.Model): 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    assignmentRuleName = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    assignmentObject = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    assignmentValue = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.assignmentRuleName

class assignmentRuleItem(models.Model): 
    Jira_Column = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    RelationalOperators= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Jira_Value = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # LogicalOperator = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    Rule_No = models.ForeignKey(assignmentRule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

And that is my view.py

```
def rule_assignment_developer(request):
    rules = list(assignmentRule.objects.values_list('id','assignmentValue','assignmentRuleName','assignmentObject').filter(assignmentObject = 'Developer'))
    for rule in rules:
        # print(rule[1])
        assignmentRuleItems = list(assignmentRuleItem.objects.values_list('Jira_Column', 'RelationalOperators', 'Jira_Value').filter(Rule_No = rule[0]))
        AR = len(assignmentRuleItems)
        print(AR)
        myString = ''
        for i in range(AR):
            kwargs = {}
            if myString == "":
                myString = myString + assignmentRuleItems[i][0] + assignmentRuleItems[i][1]+assignmentRuleItems[i][2] 
            else:
                myString = myString+","+assignmentRuleItems[i][0]+assignmentRuleItems[i][1]+assignmentRuleItems[i][2] 
        for e in myString.split(','):
            k, v = e.split('=')
            kwargs[k] = v
        print(kwargs)
        js = jira.objects.filter(**kwargs)
        js.update(Developers=rule[1])
        for object in js:
            object.save()        
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/DependencyManagement')
```

How to get rid of this problem as I have to assign the string value into foreignkey column. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest some changes in this function, in going to make some changes to it, and then I'm going to comment on what I did.

```
def rule_assignment_developer(request):
    rules = assignmentRule.objects.filter(assignmentObject = 'Developer')
    if rules.exists():
        rule = rules[0]
        assignmentRuleItems = assignmentRuleItem.objects.filter(Rule_No = rule)
        for i in range(len(assignmentRuleItems)):
            kwargs = {}
            myString = assignmentRuleItems[i][0] + assignmentRuleItems[i][1]+assignmentRuleItems[i][2] 
        for e in myString.split(','):
            k, v = e.split('=')
            kwargs[k] = v
        js = jira.objects.filter(**kwargs)
        js.update(Developers=rule)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/DependencyManagement')
```

First thing that I changed is the way that you are filtering the   `assignmentRule` objects, if you filter for those in the way that you are doing you are going to end up with a list of strings, because you set the `__str__` of the object to be its name, and you can't do much with that list of strings, by filtering in the way that I did, you will have a list of the objects, this way you have access to all the fields in those objects, so you don't need `values_list` anymore.
Second thing that I was a condition to see if the list of objects exist, and if that condition is met I'm creating a variable called `rule` that will receive the first object of the list of objects that we have, now if you do for example `print(rule.pk)` you are going to print the pk of that object, which is perfect, because now you can modify the Developers field on the Jira object later on
third thing that I did was removing an if statement that you did, that was unnecessary, you just declared myString as `''` and then just did a condition to do something if it had that value, which is not necessary, since you just set the variable to have that value, and then did nothing else to change that value, it is obvious that the condition is going to be met, so it is better to just take that out.
Fourth thing that I did is I just took out the last loop on the function that was meant to save the objects on the db, you don't need this, the update function already does that, save is just for new objects.

The problem that you had with passing a string into a ForeignField is just unsolvable, you need to pass an object into that field, and the way that this object is represented is by its pk/id, so this is why it gives you that error

You are doing some more unnecessary stuff on the end of the function, specially with that kwargs and the myString variable, but to be honest, I don't think that I'm good enough to fix those, I hope I've helped, good luck on the project.

Comment: Hi @MBsola using your code i'm getting error on line myString = myString + assignmentRuleItems[i][0] + assignmentRuleItems[i][1]+assignmentRuleItems[i][2]

Comment: error is 'assignmentRuleItem' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try creating a list of strings, and then you can do: `list.append(assignmentRuleItems[i])`, this will add the assignmentRuleItems in a list of strings, I wouldn't do that to be honest, I don't quite understand why you're creating this myString variable in your code, but I would just use assignmentRuleItems on itself, as a list of objects as we did with the rules variable.

Comment: How to create list of string here ?? i'm new in this field actually

Comment: use `list = []`, then you will have a blank list